Are there other Euclidean lattices whose construction is based on number theoretic identities?
In the book of Conway and Sloane about Sphere packings and Lattices, which is referenced by the video of Borcherds a construction of the Leech Lattice based on the number theoretic identity:
$$1^2+2^2+\cdots+24^2=70^2$$
is presented. I am asking myself if there are other lattices with possibly other properties, which are based on number theoretic identities?
I will make a more concrete question:
Let $J_k(n)$ be the Jordan totient function. In Wikipedia it is mentioned that :
$$\sum_{d|n}J_k(n) = n^k$$
We might consider these identities to be useful in constructing Lattices and try to understand the Leech lattice construction from this point of view:
Let $k=2$:
We embedd the number $n$ in Euclidean space with
$$\phi_2(n) := \sum_{d|n} \sqrt{J_2(d)}e_d$$
where $e_i$ is the standard basis in Euclidean space.
Then we have:
$$\langle \phi_2(n),\phi_2(n) \rangle   = \sum_{d|n}J_2(d) = n^2$$
Instead of directly looking at the Lorentzian space, we look at the Eucldiean space and define:
$$w := \phi_2(n) , \hat{w} := \{(x_1,\cdots,x_{\tau(n)})\mid \langle  w, x \rangle \in \mathbb{Z} \text{ and }  \langle  w, x \rangle \equiv 0 \bmod(n) \text{ and } x_i \in \mathbf{O}_K\}$$
where $K := \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{J_2(d)}\mid d \text{ divides } n)$ is the number field and $O_K$ is the ring of integers.
We observe as in Conway's and Sloane's construction, that $w \in \hat{w}$ so one could form
$$\hat{w} /w$$
but I am not sure if this gives a lattice or not.
So my question is:

if there are other identities like the $24$ identity but it generates different lattices?
Does the construction above yield a lattice for each $n$ and if so, what properties do this lattices have?

Thanks for your help.

I recommend Wolfgang Ebeling, Lattices and codes. https://archive.org/details/latticescodescou0000ebel   I see, preview just a few pages.  Very nice, I used it for a paper  where I helped Pete L. Clark  with one section; the trick, also due to Conway, is described very well. I emailed Ebeling about the article,  he said there was not enough time to get that usage into the third edition. http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/Clark_Jagy_11_13_2013.pdf

@WillJagy: Thanks for the pointer. I will take a look.
